# Function for adding a column in a data.frame if it is not already in it

Tags: r

Greeting,

I am currently trying to set up a function to add a column to a dataframe if it doesn't already exists.
Let's say columns is a vector of names I want in my dataframe.
Here is what I have so far... For some reasons it adds an "i" column and that's it.
I think the problem should come from the definition of i in the function, but I've tried several changes and that's still not working.
Any clue ? Thanks a lot!

```
add_columns <- function(x){
'%!in%' <- function(u,v)!('%in%'(u,v))
for(i in columns){
if(i %!in% colnames(x)) {
  x$"i" <-100
  return(x)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: "a function to add a function to a dataframe" - typo?

Comment: Can't use strings with `$`, use `[[` instead. `x[[i]] <- 100`. Also, as soon as `return()` is called, the function ends. You want the `return()` to be *after* the `for` loop, not inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gregor, that's working perfectly!